# How to fix this error “IndexError: image index out of range”?

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library

The main task is to display an image with the `.obj` format

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import re

scr_x = 800
scr_y = scr_x
half_scr_x = int(scr_x / 2)
half_scr_y = int(scr_y / 2)
img = Image.new('RGB', (scr_x+1, scr_y+1) , 'black')
canvas_pixels = img.load()
color = (255,255,255)
f = open('male_head.obj','r')
lines = f.read()
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    try:
        v, x, y, z, = re.split('\s+', line)
    except:
        continue
    if v == 'v':
        x = int((float(x) + 1) * half_scr_x)
        y = scr_y - int((float(y) + 1) * half_scr_y)
        canvas_pixels[x, y] = color
img.show()
```

error :

```
canvas_pixels[x, y] = colour
IndexError: image index out of range
```

*The **`male_head.obj`** file is located in the project folder.*

Comment: Please [edit] and add the data for a small sample .obj image file to your question to make it a runnable [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like color doses't fit the specifications of canvas_pixels[x, y]. You should look how the color variable is structured.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect your x and y values from the file to be in the range (-1, 1).  If you get an exact -1 or 1, you will get an out of bounds value.  The easiest way to fix that is just to clip it:

```
x = min(scr_x - 1, max(0, x))
y = min(scr_y - 1, max(0, y))
```